# What are the pros and cons of Graduate program or Junior Management program in industry after a PhD?

Tags: career-development, first-job, graduate

I am a PhD student and will graduate in next few months. I want to switch to industry, preferably in a tech-management role down the line. During my job search I came across Trainee programs such as graduate program or junior manager program. These programs seem to allow one to ease into industry after a quick intro to different sector the company participates in.

What can I expect to gain from participating in such a program? Are there any pitfalls I should be wary of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Furthering your education is always a worthwhile endeavour.

However, for a multitude of reasons, the decision to commit to a new education program is rarely a black and white one. Only you can decide if the financials, ROI, impact on your personal/family life etc. are right for you.

In terms of management: doing the job is often a very different proposition to managing a group of people doing the job.  An ability to walk the walk and talk the talk is definitely a good start.  You also need to manage people and personalities,  work with external stakeholders, manage priorities, anticipate and mitigate risks, make key decisions, handle slippage, fulfil reporting requirements, and so on. It can also bring higher levels of pressure and stress.

You don't *need* formal management training to take on a management role. You may start off a little shaky and uncertain but you'll soon find your feet, develop your confidence and grow into the role. It's a well-worn path taken by millions of people the world over.  In fact I would imagine the vast majority of people in leadership roles had done no management training before taking their first leadership role (I have no data or research to back that up - and am happy to be corrected)

What something like a junior management program might do is give you more confidence in your ability to do the job and a foundation that will help you adapt and find your feet more quickly. It could also be beneficial as a tie-breaker between you and another candidate.

Only you can decide if it's "worth going for" though.

Good luck!